# Nullable int with Required attribute in Realms does not get stored

Tags: realm

What is going on here? Nullable ints appear to be fine, but as soon as you make it [Required], it gets stored as 0.

[image]

Assertion failure
Expected: 2
But was:  0

Comment: Also... If Item is part of a collection, it appears to count up.  So the first item added to the collection will have RequiredNumber set to 0 by the Add method, the next one added will be set to 1, then 2, then 3, and so on.

Comment: I'm using Realm v5.1.2 (i.e. the latest version)

Comment: Looks like this broke in version 5.0.1.  It works as expected in 4.3.0.

Comment: This bug has been picked up by a member of the Realms team.
https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/2085